# Receiving response from server using I/O in C with sockets

Tags: c, sockets, get, fgets, recv

I'm trying to make a simple web client using sockets. I send a GET request to a web page and want to receive an HTML file. I know I can receive using `recv()`, but I want to do this using a `FILE`. I'm using `fdopen` to wrap the socket in a `FILE`. Now I can use `fgetc()` to read the response. However, `fgets()` fails - maybe I'm using it wrong. Any way to easily read the HTTP response line by line?

This works:

```
FILE *input = fdopen(mySocket, "r");

while(!feof(input))
{
   printf("%c", fgetc(input));
}
```

I need something along these lines:

```
FILE *input = fdopen(mySocket, "r");
char c[2000];
while(fgets(c, sizeof(c), input) != NULL)
{
   printf("%s\n", c);
}
```

If there is any other convenient way to read the response, please advise.

Comment: Reading a response which does not include new line characters line by line seems difficult to me, to not say impossible by definition.

Comment: Actually I think the response does have new line characters. But for some reason, I can't get fgets to read it right.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Hint:  `#include <errno.h>` `perror("fgets:");`

Comment: Did you try with `char c[1];`?

Comment: Are you sure `input != NULL`?

Comment: Always check error after calling any open function (`perror` is your friend for quick console error reporting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added error checking and it works now. The input was indeed NULL because my request never went through. Thanks!

```
FILE *input= fdopen(mySocket, "r");
if(input== NULL)
{
printf("Error");
    exit 1;
}

char c[2000];
while(fgets(c, sizeof(c), input) != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", c);
}
```